# Кеширование и обновление файлов

Tags: nginx, браузер, кэширование, img, javascript

Есть рабочий сайт, есть пользователи, есть кеширование файлов (css, img, js) во всех браузерах - есть проблема.

Проблема: при изменении js, css - они не обновляются пока не нажмешь f5 (Опере по крайней мере так) и соответственно все кривится и не работает.

Как решить?

Comment: Элементарно — добавлять в конце файлов (?1) (/messages.js?1). 1 - версия файла. Но файлов этих много и как автоматизировать процесс? Знаю что сделано вот так во ВКонтакте.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант создать обработчик на PHP, устанавливать заголовки last-modified по времени изменения файла. Если файл не изменён(filemtime) и есть в кеше браузера (If-Modified-Since) - 304, изменён - 200, отдаём файл, меняем last-modified
У меня так работает, нагрузки на сервер практически не накладывает

Comment: Нет-нет. У меня вся статика только nginx.

Comment: нужно было указать в посте

Comment: @Gedweb, виноват.

Comment: ну если вы меняете эти файлы и не нужно динамический проверять (т.е Вы точно знаете что вот его изменили и теперь надо перегрузить) просто напишите в теге script
<script src="название файла.js?1(след обновелние 2 и тд)" ...

Comment: @ilyas, ну да. Это самое простое решение.